# Typescript error TS2393: Duplicate function implementation in a Node/Express app

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I have a node + express application where I'm using TypeScript.  I have a few API routes where I declared a function in each that looks like:

```
function cleanReqBody(req) {
  req.body.createdBy = req.user;
  req.body.modifiedBy = req.user;
  req.body.modified = new Date();
}
```

When running tsc against my code, I get `TS2393: Duplicate function implementation`.  I don't really understand why.  I can understand if this was client side code where it would think both functions are on the same scope (window) but why would that apply to node modules?  Aren't each of my node routes using separate node modules that don't share scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Aren't each of my node routes using separate node modules that don't share scope
>
> That is true at runtime. However *TypeSript* will only know of this fact if your file contains a root level `import` or `export` statement.([more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html))

If you modify *each* file with the error like:

```
function cleanReqBody(req) {
  req.body.createdBy = req.user;
  req.body.modifiedBy = req.user;
  req.body.modified = new Date();
}
export let something = 123;
```

The problems should go away.

PS: Note that if you are not using `import`/`export` you are missing out a big advantage of TypeScript understanding the Node.JS module system and helping you maintain file modules.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I read through your docs on import/export.  I'm trying to switch over but ran into an issue.  Follow up question asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399220/typescript-node-import-require-external-module-using-a-symlink-in-path