# Typescript Node import/require external module using a symlink in path

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm migrating a Node + Express application to TypeScript and am trying to use external modules.  I was using the [symlink trick](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#1-the-symlink) to not have to worry about relative paths.

Works (no tsc warning):

```
var authz = require('LIB/app/authorization');
import authz = require('../..//app/authorization');
```

Doesn't work with symlink (tsc gives warning `TS2307: Cannot find module 'LIB/app/authorization'.`):

```
var authz = require('LIB/app/authorization');
```

I believe it doesn't work due to this [TypeScript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/247).  My question is, which of the [possible options](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520) to avoid relative path require statements works in TypeScript.  Is there a preferred option?

Answer (score 0):

Do what issacs says : https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#gistcomment-972519

Have different modules +win win+. Note : you need typescript nightly to be able to use `.ts` files from different `node_modules`.

## Alternative

- `grunt-ts` transforms https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts#transforms take the burden off of relative paths
- Otherwise *don't use hacks* and use *relative paths*. You IDE should provide completions for you (checkout https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript

Comment: I currently have 469 directories inside node_modules thanks to all the dependencies of the packages I use (and I thought my app was on the small side!).  Placing my own modules inside a massive node_modules directory seems ugly to me.  The "grunt-ts" alternative looks cool but if mocha needs to do a compile, this hack won't apply.